# Convert image to individual cell value to sort in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This issue is related to Microsoft Excel 2016.
I have an excel file where the column cell values are filled with images, and the Filter is not applying on the images. Is there any other way where we can either convert the image to cell value by converting the Image with Number or color to make it easy for filter?

Want to filter the column Shapes with :) so that the final result after filter should show me Sr.No 2,3,5,7
[image: Want to filter the column Shapes with :) so that the final result after filter should show me Sr.No 2,3,5,7]

Filter option will list me Blanks only
[image: Filter option will list me Blanks only]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to place the name of each picture in the cell the picture is located in

```
Sub setPicNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim curPic As Shape

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each curPic In ws.Shapes
        curPic.TopLeftCell.Value = curPic.Name 'Or use curPic.BottomRightCell, or combine the two to get TopRight or BottomLeft
    Next curPic
End Sub
```